# Not all variables recursively expanded in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I was just playing around with Makefiles, and I'm trying to understand why some variables get expanded twice, while some others get expanded only once. Suppose the following Makefile:

```
FILE := $(shell mktemp)
TEMP = $(shell mktemp)
CONTENTS = $(shell cat $(FILE))
test:
    echo $(TEMP)
    echo $(CONTENTS)
    echo test > $(FILE)
    echo $(CONTENTS)
    echo $(TEMP)
```

Running `make test` outputs the following:

```
echo /tmp/tmp.ZWFtOiCG9v
/tmp/tmp.ZWFtOiCG9v
echo

echo test > /tmp/tmp.FEubzF4Gwa
echo

echo /tmp/tmp.OIKSGVvY1l
/tmp/tmp.OIKSGVvY1l
```

How come `TEMP` gets expanded each time it's called, but `CONTENTS` is only expanded once?

I'm running GNU Make 3.82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables for a recipe are all expanded when the recipe *begins* to execute:

```
#forcing `bash` to prevent `make` from using its builtin shell
$ strace -t -e execve -f make -d SHELL=/bin/bash test >output 2>&1
$ cat output # with irrelevant bits elided
17:20:48 execve("/usr/bin/make", ["make", "-d", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "test"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
 <lots of lines omitted>
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....

# prepare the recipe
Considering target file 'test'.
 File 'test' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'test'.
Must remake target 'test'.

# expand $(DATE) the first time
strace: Process 32729 attached
[pid 32729] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "date"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32729] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32729] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32729, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---

# expand $(FILE) the first time
strace: Process 32730 attached
[pid 32730] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "mktemp"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32730] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/mktemp", ["mktemp"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32730] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32730, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---

# expand $(DATE) the second time
strace: Process 32731 attached
[pid 32731] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "date"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32731] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32731] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32731, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---

# expand $(FILE) the second time
strace: Process 32732 attached
[pid 32732] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "mktemp"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32732] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/mktemp", ["mktemp"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32732] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32732, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---

# begin executing the recipe
strace: Process 32733 attached
Putting child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32733 on the chain.
Live child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32733 
[pid 32733] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo Tue Jun 26 17:20:48 PDT 201"...], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
Tue Jun 26 17:20:48 PDT 2018
[pid 32733] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32733, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Reaping winning child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32733 
strace: Process 32734 attached
Live child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32734 
[pid 32734] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo /tmp/tmp.nWxcC4KeVf"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
/tmp/tmp.nWxcC4KeVf
[pid 32734] 17:20:48 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:48 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32734, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Reaping winning child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32734 

# significant time doesn't pass until here
sleep 3
strace: Process 32735 attached
Live child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32735 
[pid 32735] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 3"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32735] 17:20:48 execve("/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "3"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32735] 17:20:51 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:51 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32735, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Reaping winning child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32735 
strace: Process 32736 attached
Live child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32736 
[pid 32736] 17:20:51 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo Tue Jun 26 17:20:48 PDT 201"...], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
Tue Jun 26 17:20:48 PDT 2018
[pid 32736] 17:20:51 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:51 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32736, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Reaping winning child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32736 
strace: Process 32737 attached
Live child 0x5629c95cb0c0 (test) PID 32737 
[pid 32737] 17:20:51 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo /tmp/tmp.QgNem5ezr0"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
/tmp/tmp.QgNem5ezr0
[pid 32737] 17:20:51 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:20:51 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32737, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Reaping winning child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32737 
Removing child 0x5629c95cb0c0 PID 32737 from chain.
Successfully remade target file 'test'.
17:20:51 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

This makes sense, even without `.ONESHELL`, because variables can expand to multiple lines, which need to be executed separately.

Comment: Edited my original question to make @o11c's answer clearer. Since the variables get expanded before anything is actually done, it means the file is still empty when it gets expanded. One way to get around it would be to `$(eval CONTENTS:=$(shell cat $(FILE)))`

Comment: Just to be very clear, the variable `CONTENTS` _is_ being expanded multiple times.  It's just that all instances of it are being expanded before any of the recipe is invoked so they all expand to the same thing.

Comment: Yep, I just changed the question so that it would be clearer that `CONTENTS` was supposed to be very different if it was getting expanded at the time at which it's called rather than when the recipe starts